# SQL foreign key is not referenced by another table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

How could I relate the following foreign key to this table?

what I want is to have a relation between `time_slot` and `checkup _appt` table. I would like to be able to do a one to many relationships, or one one as well

```
CREATE TABLE time_slot
(
    slot_id varchar(4),
    adoption_id varchar(8),
    day varchar(1),
    req_appt_id varchar(8),
    start_hr numeric(2) check (start_hr >= 0 and start_hr < 24),
    start_min numeric(2) check (start_min >= 0 and start_min < 60),
    end_hr numeric(2) check (end_hr >= 0 and end_hr < 24),
    end_min numeric(2) check (end_min >= 0 and end_min < 60),

    primary key (slot_id, req_appt_id, adoption_id),
);
 
CREATE TABLE well_check_up 
(
    slot_id varchar(4),
    adoption_id varchar(8),
    req_appt_id varchar(8),
    day varchar(1),

    PRIMARY KEY (slot_id, req_appt_id, adoption_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (req_appt_id) REFERENCES time_slot (slot_id, req_appt_id, adoption_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary Key primary key (time_slot_id, day,start_min,req_appt_id,adoption_id),); on time slot, is a composed primary Key. You need to reference ALL of them on well_check, not only req_appt_id.

Like this

```
 Reference Time_slot(time_slot_id, 
 day,start_min,req_appt_id,adoption_id).
```

This means you Will have to add these columns on Well_check as well.

Comment: please see my edits, I did that but still missing something

Comment: In this case You want your PRIMARY KEY and FK to be the same?    CREATE TABLE  well_check_up .....
    FOREIGN KEY (slot_id,req_appt_id,adoption_id) REFERENCES time_slot(slot_id,req_appt_id,adoption_id)
       ); See that the FK must match the PK of Time_slot.